# How to filter in python eve by object id string without schema

Tags: python, eve

I am using python eve to build a data storage service. All my collections are schemaless, so I've set `ALLOW_UNKNOWN` setting to True. Everything works fine except with fields referencing another ones. I'm trying to request a collection filtering by an object id string and I am always getting an empty list.

For example, I have `apps` and `task` collections set in `DOMAIN` setting.

The sequence of request I do is as follow:

POST '/apps':

```
{
    "name": "test"
}
```

GET '/apps':

```
{
    "_items": [
        {
            "_id": "5afb45872fb8d57c7d93d8fa",
            "name": "Test app",
            "_updated": "Tue, 15 May 2018 20:39:35 GMT",
            "_created": "Tue, 15 May 2018 20:39:35 GMT"
        }
    ],
    "_meta": {
        "page": 1,
        "max_results": 25,
        "total": 1
    }
}
```

POST '/tasks':

```
{
    "title": "Check log files",
    "app_id": "5afb45872fb8d57c7d93d8fa"
}
```

GET '/tasks':

```
{
    "_items": [
        {
            "_id": "5afb4bcd2fb8d57c7d93d912",
            "title": "Check log files",
            "app_id": "5afb45872fb8d57c7d93d8fa",
            "_updated": "Tue, 15 May 2018 21:06:21 GMT",
            "_created": "Tue, 15 May 2018 21:06:21 GMT"
        }
    ],
    "_meta": {
        "page": 1,
        "max_results": 25,
        "total": 1
    }
}
```

GET '/tasks/?where={"app_id": "5afb45872fb8d57c7d93d8fa"}:

```
{
    "_items": [],
    "_meta": {
        "page": 1,
        "max_results": 25,
        "total": 0
    }
}
```

My question are:

- How can I post an ObjectId field without a defined schema?
- How can I retrieve tasks filtering by `app_id`?

Looking at docs I've found the `query_objectid_as_string` setting, however document endpoints return 404 error.

GET /tasks/5afb4bcd2fb8d57c7d93d912 -> Not found

Comment: in your responses is absent `_links` and some other fields that means your changed standart configuration. Compare with `curl http://eve-demo.herokuapp.com/people | json_pp`